# Не срабатывает обработчик событий on

Tags: html, jquery

**Что имеем?**

1. Кнопку по нажатию которой подгружается контент на страницу методом $.ajax
2. Подгруженный контент

**Примерная HTML разметка**

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="get">
///Контент который подгрузится после нажатия
<div class="content">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**Усложненый вариант**

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="get">
    ///Контент который подгрузится после нажатия
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sub_item"></div>
        <div class="sub_item"></div>
        <div class="sub_item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
```

**JS(Jquery код)**

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".content",function(){
    $(".content").on("mouseenter","item",function(){
    alert("Вы навели мышью на item");
    });
});
```

**Для усложненного варианта**

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".content",function(){
    $(".content").on("mouseenter","item",function(){
    /// Какие-то действия
    alert("Вы навели мышью на item");
    });
    $(".content").on("mouseenter","sub_item",function(){
    /// Какие-то действия
    alert("Вы навели мышью на sub_item");
    });
});
```

Суть: Если навести мышью на любой item впервые сообщения не будет, а на повторный раз появится

**Что делать?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш код работает так:

При первом наведении на `item` срабатывает эта функция :

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".content",function(){


});
```

и выполняет все что у нее внутри. То есть вторую вложенную фунцкцию :

```
$(".content").on("mouseenter","item",function(){
    alert("Вы навели мышью на item");
});
```

И только в этой вложеной функции навешивается новый обработчик. причем этот обработчик (один и тот же каждый раз) навешивается  каждый раз когда Вы проводите мышкой над классом `.content`

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".content > .item",function(){

    alert("Вы навели мышью на item");

});
```

Селектор `".content > item"` означает: все елементы `item` у которых родительский элемент имеет класс `content`.

Пример jsfiddle [попробовать](https://jsfiddle.net/7j9oz9y5/).

**Update:**
Если я правильно понял, то можно навешивать обработчики таким образом:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
</div>


$( document ).ready(function() {
        setEventHandlers();
});

function setEventHandlers(){

    $(".content > .item1").on("mouseenter",function(){
    alert("Вы навели мышью на клас item1 ");
    });

  $(".content > .item2").on("mouseenter",function(){
    alert("Вы навели мышью на клас item2 ");
    });

  $(".content > .item3").on("mouseenter",function(){
    alert("Вы навели мышью на клас item3 ");
    });

}
```

Comment: А есть альтернативы?

Comment: @MaximPro, есть, но нужно больше информации от Вас что вы хотите.

Comment: Ну допустим я хочу под общий обработчик поместить кучу разных обработчиков на другие элементы, а писать через запятую не хочется
Хотелось бы сохранить мою конструкцию, или подобие

Comment: @MaximPro, добавил вариант. Сразу скажу, "под общий обработчик поместить кучу разных обработчиков на другие элементы" идея непонятная и, наверное, лучше от нее воздержаться. Либо расскажитенам какие цели под этим преследуются?

Comment: увидел, а это будет работать с подгруженным контентом?

Comment: @MaximPro, будет просто навешивайте обработчики как только получили success от ajax. то есть вызывайте  setEventHandlers(); в функции success или .done, в зависмости от того что используете.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас опробую

Comment: Работает! Сверху товарищ Sergey Gornostaev что-то писал про обработчики, хотелось бы задать вопрос почему он не видит вложенный обработчик?

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что обработчик события mouseenter для item устанавливается в обработчике mouseenter для .content. Когда вы наводите в первый раз, его ещё нет.

Comment: и как это исправить? не могу сообразить